# Unable to execute Python Script directly

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am unable to execute Python Script directly.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0qzP.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aVd1.png)

whereas path to Python Environemnt is as follows:

root@UbuntuDockerGuest-1:~# python -c "import os; print(os.environ['_'])"

/usr/bin/python

I am not sure how to add it correctly in the begining of the program?

Thank you.

Just want to test running python script directly

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra blank line at the top of the file. The `#!` have to be the first two bytes of the file, no whitespace or newline before them.

Also, the path after the `#!` has to be `/usr/bin/python` or `/usr/bin/env python`, not `/usr/bin python`.

Answer (score -1):

Delete the line with the shebang.

`Ctrl + K` on:

```
#! usr / bin + python
```

Hit **Save**. You are done.

Now can run the `.py` script:

```
python <MyScript.py>
```

Give yourself a pat on the back for job well done!